# Accessing State inside an Event setup through Reference (Reactjs)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I am trying to use a library called [payform](https://github.com/jondavidjohn/payform) and while someone is typing in a credit card number I want to use a built in function of payform that tells me what credit card it is.

```
payform.parseCardType();
```

and example can be seen [here](https://jondavidjohn.github.io/payform/) at first I tried to add a reference

```
 componentDidMount() {
   payform.cardNumberInput(this.cardNumberRef.current);
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.cardNumberRef = React.createRef();
  }

  @action
  onCardNumberChange = event => {
    console.log('fa5r1515fkf');
  //  this.cardType = payform.parseCardType(event.target.value);
  }

<input className="input" type="text" ref={this.cardNumberRef} onChange={this.onCardNumberChange} />
```

This did not work and I think it because it has it's own change events and I think it sort hijacks the onChange.

So what I had to do is this

```
 componentDidMount() {
    let that = this;
    this.cardNumberRef.current.addEventListener('input', function(event){
      runInAction(() => {
        that.cardType = payform.parseCardType(event.target.value);
      });
    });
   payform.cardNumberInput(this.cardNumberRef.current);
  }
```

I don't really know what 'input' really means as I would would have used 'onChange' but in [their example](https://github.com/jondavidjohn/payform/blob/gh-pages/javascripts/form.js) I saw they used it.

Either way though I am not sure if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: sorry what's exactly the issue ? what does print `event.target.value` ?

Comment: I am asking if there is a better way to achieve what I am trying to do.  Which is trying to get a value from a library that needs me to create a reference and then set it into state.

Comment: Personally, i would have done it like you did. Maybe with arrow function which we avoid doing `let that = this` and just `this.cardNumberRef.current.addEventListener('input', event => runInAction(() => this.cardType = ...`